# isotope items disappearing when resize browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-isotope

I hacked an isotope combofilter with checkboxes, but here is the problem with the isotope items; They are disappearing when resizing browser window.

I dont why they are not displaying when I change the size of the browser!

Please so help!!

Normaly I use isotope V2. Here in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cagdas/rm7o686v/1/), there is np with the window resizing however I used isotope v1..

I am driving crazy, when items disappeared I need to trigger by clicking a select button, then its going fine.

```
var $containerii;
    var filters = {};


jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var $containerii = $('.isotope').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.isotope-item'

    });



    getContent: '.isotope-item li'

    var $filterDisplay = $('#filter-display');

    $containerii.isotope();
    // do stuff when checkbox change
    $('#options').on('change', function (jQEvent) {
        var $checkbox = $(jQEvent.target);
        manageCheckbox($checkbox);

        var comboFilter = getComboFilter(filters);

        $containerii.isotope({ filter: comboFilter });

        $filterDisplay.text(comboFilter);
    });


});




function getContent() {

    var items = document.getElementById("containerii")
}







 function getComboFilter(filters) {
   var i = 0;
   var comboFilters = [];
   var message = [];

   for (var prop in filters) {
      message.push(filters[prop].join(' '));
      var filterGroup = filters[prop];
      // skip to next filter group if it doesn't have any values
      if (!filterGroup.length) {
          continue;
      }
      if (i === 0) {
          // copy to new array
          comboFilters = filterGroup.slice(0);
      } else {
          var filterSelectors = [];
          // copy to fresh array
          var groupCombo = comboFilters.slice(0); // [ A, B ]
          // merge filter Groups
          for (var k = 0, len3 = filterGroup.length; k < len3; k++) {
              for (var j = 0, len2 = groupCombo.length; j < len2; j++) {
                  filterSelectors.push(groupCombo[j] + filterGroup[k]); // [ 1, 2 ]
              }

          }
          // apply filter selectors to combo filters for next group
          comboFilters = filterSelectors;
      }
      i++;
  }

  var comboFilter = comboFilters.join(', ');
  return comboFilter;
 }

function manageCheckbox($checkbox) {
  var checkbox = $checkbox[0];

  var group = $checkbox.parents('.option-set').attr('data-group');
  // create array for filter group, if not there yet
  var filterGroup = filters[group];
  if (!filterGroup) {
      filterGroup = filters[group] = [];
  }

  var isAll = $checkbox.hasClass('all');
  // reset filter group if the all box was checked
  if (isAll) {
      delete filters[group];
      if (!checkbox.checked) {
          checkbox.checked = 'checked';
      }
  }
  // index of
  var index = $.inArray(checkbox.value, filterGroup);

  if (checkbox.checked) {
      var selector = isAll ? 'input' : 'input.all';
      $checkbox.siblings(selector).removeAttr('checked');


      if (!isAll && index === -1) {
          // add filter to group
          filters[group].push(checkbox.value);
      }

  } else if (!isAll) {
      // remove filter from group
      filters[group].splice(index, 1);
      // if unchecked the last box, check the all
      if (!$checkbox.siblings('[checked]').length) {
          $checkbox.siblings('input.all').attr('checked', 'checked');
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: have you tried to reinitialize isotope on resize?

Comment: @Escobear I tried window resize It didnt work out the problem, but maybe I used it in a wrong way, i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If your using isotope v2, try this:

```
var $containerii = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
    isResizeBound: true
});
```

v1.5, [this:](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/options.html#resizable)

ADDENDUM

I don't see anything disappearing, just the col-md-10 shifting down when you resize your window. I changed the layout to avoid the shift and it seems to resize as it should.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/g5tk42vk/)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me (was having the resize issue for a long time).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for helps and valuable responses. Finally I solved my problem by using trigger isotope on window resize at the end of the code.

```
 $(window).on('resize', function () {
     $containerii = $('.isotope');
     triggerIsotope();
 });
```